# Clone custom object record via Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, clone

I want to clone a custom object's record via a Salesforce1 chatter action. But for some reason, for that particular object there is no "Clone" action available.

However, I have another custom object where the clone action **is** available, and for the life of me, I can't figure out why it's available on that one object but not on the other.

Both of them have chatter feed tracking enabled.

Attached a screenshot of the custom object which has the clone action

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my Clone button was overridden with a visualforce page in the standard salesforce environment, this way the button isn't available as a Salesforce1 action.

Make sure your clone button isn't overridden.